# Magento2 create new sample data

Tags: magento2, chmod, sample-data

I had a fresh install of Magento2 and was trying to install sample data by bin/magento sampledata:deploy but it gave back error In PluginManager.php(196) : eval()'d code line 188:
chmod(): Operation not permitted . There is an error during sample data deployment. Composer file will be reverted .

Do somebody know what have gone wrong ?

Answer (score 1):

That is probably a permission issue.
Go to root

```
sudo su
```

Then installed magento directory:

```
cd var/www/html/{magento Directory}
```

Run command:

```
php bin/magento sampledata:deploy
```

Make sure to run indexing and clean the cache after that:

```
php bin/magento indexer:reindex
php bin/magento c:f
```